# Does Swansong count for Berserker?

Tags: payday-2

When Swansong is active, is Beserker also active? I understand that the player is below the Beserker threshold (as you would have 0% of your hp max), but I want to double check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Payday 2 Wiki for Swansong](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Swan_Song):

> Additionally, the skill is complemented by several damage-based perks: under the right circumstances, Enforcer skills like aced Berserker, aced Shotgun Impact, and basic Underdog can cause devastating damage.

It looks like yes it does work along with it.

Answer (score 2):

They do stack, but you can't activate overkill with HE rounds so you might need to use a normal a shotty to activate it then get 5 secs of huge damage, or go without it

Comment: Do you have a source for this information?

Comment: I play the game a lot